# Android Studio 3.0 canary 1 : SQL syntax error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have a problem after upgraded to Android Studio 3.0 canary 1 from Android Studio 2.3

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Contract.COUNTRY_PATH + " (" +
                Contract.Country._ID + " INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT , " +
                Contract.Country.COLUMN_CITY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                Contract.Country.COLUMN_COUNTRY_NAME + " TEXT," +
                Contract.Country.COLUMN_SUNRISE + " INTEGER," +
                Contract.Country.COLUMN_SUNSET + " INTEGER) ");
```

It shows an error.

```
'(',')',<column constraint> or comma expected ,got 'AUTO'
```

It was fine with Android Studio 2.3.
Any suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried with `AUTO_INCREMENT ` ? ("_" instead of empty space)

Comment: Yes, the same problem.

Comment: How about adding `NOT NULL` constraint?

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem.

Comment: I have also tried AUTOINCREMENT without spaces or underscore.

Comment: Than most likely its a bug, its preview version anyway. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL syntax checker in Android Studio 3 is stricter than sqlite itself.

`INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT` in sqlite itself basically just results in a column with integer affinity. The mistyped `AUTO INCREMENT` is just noise. That's why it gets flagged in Studio but does not cause a syntax error in sqlite.

If you want an autoincrementing column, make it `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`. If you really need the rowid reuse avoidance, then the column should be `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`. Note that you can only have one primary key column in a table. See also: https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 1):

Do not put any spaces in you column name.

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 beta7. Same problem still exists.

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE TABLE yourtablename (id INTEGER primary key autoincrement NOT NULL, name TEXT, description TEXT, expValue INTEGER, category INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES categories (id), date TEXT)
```

Comment: Could you add some more explanation?