# <expr> expected, got '?'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

When typing a SQLite statement as a string literal in a class in Android Studio, the IDE gives me this warning: `"<expr> expected, got '?'"`.

I don't understand what this means, but the code is working fine, and I'd like to disable the inspection. But I don't know which inspection is causing it. There are thousands of them, and searching for  or expected yields no useful results.

The version of Android Studio is 3.0. It's happening with a whole bunch of different statements, but a typical one looks like this:

```java
SQLiteStatement st = db.compileStatement(
   "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO routes(route_code, route_desc) VALUES(?,?)"
);
```

Comment: Can you post your full query statement? Also what version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Latest version (3.0). It's happening with a whole bunch of different statements, but a typical one looks like this: SQLiteStatement st = db.compileStatement("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO routes(route_code, route_desc) VALUES(?,?)");

Comment: I looked around and it appears that from Android Studio 3.0+ the SQLite syntax checker is much stricter. But I think it is expecting a space between the last comma and the question mark. Try adding the spacing and see if it works. Here some links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205651/android-studio-3-0-canary-1-sql-syntax-error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165045/android-sqlite-queries-marked-as-error-by-android-studio
Note: your code should be fine, SQLite still knows how to handle the syntax, AS just wants to enforce better syntactical habits.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Adding the space didn't fix it. In fact it's happening with some statements that only have one ?. How do I access and disable these SQLite warnings? I can't find them in the preferences anywhere.

Comment: There's a bug report about this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68403417

Comment: Thanks. For now I worked around it by declaring my string on a separate line.

Answer (score 12):

This is a bug in Android Studio 3.0 and is already reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68293745). Also this is now fixed in the 3.1 version. I am using the latest Canary 5 3.1 build and it works fine.

Since there are not going to be anymore 3.0 patches, all you can do for now is to go with the workaround or disable this lint check.

Comment: I use AS 3.01 and Lint complains about the first question mark in "INSERT INTO ... VALUES (?, ?)". I can't see any working workaround. I won't use Canary in production environment. I don't know how to disable only this check in Lint and not all syntax checks... :/

Comment: No, this bug is not fixed in AS 3.1.2

Comment: Got the same bug on 3.1.2 too