# Error in rawQuery() in SQLite

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper

 {
 public static final String DATABASE_NAME="register.db";
 public static final String TABLE_NAME="registration";
 public static final String COL_1="ID";
 public static final String COL_2="FirstName";
 public static final String COL_3="LastName";
 public static final String COL_4="Password";
 public static final String COL_5="Email";
 public static final String COL_6="Phone";

 public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);}

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table "+TABLE_NAME+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY 
     KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FirstName TEXT,LastName TEXT,Password TEXT,Email 
     TEXT,Phone TEXT)");}

 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME); //Drop 
    older table if exists
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

 public int checkusercredentials(String email,String password){

    Log.i("INISDE","CHECK USER ");
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    try{
       int i=0;
       Cursor c=null;
       c=db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+"where "+ "Email=? and 
       Password=?",new String[]{email,password});
        c.moveToNext();
        i=c.getCount();
        c.close();
        return i;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}

    return 0;
}
```

In my Code, checkusercredentials is called when user clicks SIGNIN button.

The Error that I face is in c=db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+"where "+ "Email=? and 
       Password=?",new String[]{email,password});

I get an error in the '=' symbol after Email and the error reads Expected compound operator,join operator,..., WHERE  got'='

The Logcat reads
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
Process: com.example.android.login, PID: 26858

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , 
while compiling: SELECT * FROM registrationWHERE Email=? AND Password=?

at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native 
Method)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)

at 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)

at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)

at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)

at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)

at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)

at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
                                                                           at com.example.android.login.DataBaseHelper.checkusercredentials(DataBaseHelper.java:62)
                                                                           at com.example.android.login.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:43)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

WHAT IS THE ERROR?

Comment: missing space here: `"+TABLE_NAME+"where "`

Comment: Q: `WHAT IS THE ERROR?` A: **Distraction**.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to a space missing between the table name and the WHERE keyword thus it thinks that the table name is **registrationWHERE**.

So you need to change `c=db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+"where "+ "Email=? and Password=?",new String[]{email,password});`

to

```
    c=db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where "+ "Email=? and Password=?",new String[]{email,password});
```

If you then encounter or are encountering `no such column` delete the App's data and rerun the App. This would then cause the `onCreate` method to be invoked and re-create the table. Not understanding that the `onCreate` method only automatically runs when the database is created, is a very common cause of column's not existing as code is changed in the `onCreate` method to add columns but the method doesn't run.

If you then still encounter problems then edit your question and include a description along with the stack trace from the log.

---

## EDIT

It appears that the second error is a bug (resolved in Android Studio 3.1)  [as per - `<expr>` expected, got '?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021237/expr-expected-got).

There are two was around this as per

```
    Cursor c; // No need for Cursor c = null; so just Cursor c;

    // Get-around 1 - pass where clause as a String.
    String whereclause = " WHERE Email=? AND Password=?"; // <<<<use string for the WHERE clause
    c = db.rawQuery("select * from "+
            TABLE_NAME+
            whereclause,//<<<< use string for the WHERE clause
        new String[]{email,password}
    );


    // Get-around 2 use query method as opposed to rawQuery method 
    c = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
        null,
        "Email=? AND Password=?",
        new String[]{email,password},
        null,null,null 
    );
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Brother. Although it is showing a red underline under '=' symbol signifying error, There are no error reports in the LogCat and the Program works fine.

Comment: uhhm I see what you mean. You could use `c = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,"Email=? AND Password=?",new String[]{email,password},null,null,null );` as an alternative. Not sure of the cause though, never seen that before, also I think there's another recent question re the **<expr> expected, got '?'**. [Might be this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021237/expr-expected-got)

Answer (score 0):

I did it like that...

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " //
                        + DatabaseHelper.COL_5 + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + "=?";
                cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, new String[]{userName, passLogin});
```

and its working fine now